# Encoding Html code and Insert into database

Tags: c#, html, sql, asp.net-mvc-4

I want insert html tags in encoded form into sql database table.I use MVC4 for developing this. I take the html code into the following model item.

```
public class ResourceItems
{
     public string Res_Details { get; set; }
}
```

what will be the controller/model action

Comment: my html code is in a textarea(in a form). so where i put this. In controller or model

Comment: Vauge question! plz elaborate what you want and what's your problem?

Comment: Data should be stored in its purest form, no HTML.

Answer (score 0):

To encode the string, you can use the [HttpUtility.HtmlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h.aspx) function.

```
private ActionResult Index(ResourceItem item){

    string encoded = HttpUtility.Encode(item.Res_Details);

    // Whatever you do to save to the database.
}
```

Now I don't know what your MVC code looks like, so the above example is just a guess. However the core idea of the encoding should suffice.

Comment: When you say it's not working, how is it not working? Exception being raised, the string is not encoded? Bit more info dude :)

Comment: i always get the error msg like: A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (Res_Details="<h1>dhf</h1>").

Comment: OK, take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client

Comment: But you must be careful. Don't just accept data into your controller action without encoding it. If you just accept HTML input as is, then you might be opening yourself up to some dangerous JavaScript code, for example.